# how to Notifications need WAKE_LOCK in android?

Tags: android, notifications, wakelock

how to remove this error during download image and when Updating Notification.

> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10080 nor current process
>   has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK. at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379) at
>   android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:326)
>   at
>   android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked(PowerManager.java:309)
>   at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:300) at
>   android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:128)
>   at
>   android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:104)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

for Wakelock permission in your android manifest file use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that "WAKE_LOCK" must be in CAPS for it to work... I'm not sure if this is obvious, but it wasn't for me.

Comment: I have the permission in my Manifest but I am still seeing this crash in my crashlytics dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

A wake lock is a mechanism to indicate that your application needs to have the device stay on.

If you want to keep the screen on you required this permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Call `acquire()` to acquire the wake lock and force the device to stay on at the level that was requested when the wake lock was created.

Call `release()` when you are done and don't need the lock anymore. It is very important to do this as soon as possible to avoid running down the device's battery excessively.

Fore more click  [Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)

Answer (score 0):

put all the uses-permission at the end of the manifest

Comment: it is working but not understand , can you explain ?

Comment: @YogeshRathi Refer to my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38795607/2980047